# Deploying contract to Rinkeby test network with web3.py

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

The basic tutorial on web3.py uses Web3.EthereumTesterProvider(). 
What would be the steps to deploy it to the Rinkeby test network with web3.py? There doesn't seem to be much of a guide on the official page on this matter.

Comment: I have gone through that tutorial and got it working for EthereumTesterProvider. What I wanted is a step by step guide to deploy it to the Rinkeby test net. Any resources for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTPProder:

```py
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

web3 = Web3(HTTProvider(json_rpc_url_to_your_rinkerby_node))
```